# Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory clearing out the whole database

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm currently working with a project using Hibernate + JPA.
I don't recall exactly what I changed in the project, but everytime I try to instantiate a new EntityManagerFactory, it clears out all of the data from the database.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public abstract class GenericDAO<T> {

protected Class<T> t;
protected EntityManagerFactory managerFactory;
protected EntityManager manager;
protected Session hibernateSession;

public GenericDAO(Class<T> t) {
    this.t = t;
    this.managerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hibernatePersistence");
    this.manager = this.managerFactory.createEntityManager();
    this.hibernateSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
}
```

In the line that contains "Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hibernatePersistence")", the whole database is cleared out.

I exhausted every idea for solving this issue... I hope you guys can help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property somewhere in your project (probably `persistence.xml` file) and remove it or change its value to `validate`. See also:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional

Comment: `update`, or `validate` are fine. Just avoid `drop-create`. (+1)

Comment: Nope, I tried boths suggestions and nothing helped, any other ideas??

Comment: Maybe you are using in-memory database? H2/HSQLDB? What is your JDBC URL?

Comment: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/cafeina the jdbc URL by the way

Comment: Resolved it by deleting and creating a fresh new persistence.xml. I don't know why it happened and how it happened, but now it works. Thanks for the light!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by deleting and creating a fresh new persistence.xml. Don't know why this problme occured, but nevermind, it works now...